# Monthly average of each hour dat using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have data like below

```
   Date_Time           A
2019-09-01 00:00:00  140.857143

2019-09-01 01:00:00  132.8750000

 ...        ...  ...       ...       ...

2019-09-30 22:00:00  120.419355 

2019-09-30 23:00:00  110.285714
```

I want to average over each hour of month September (9th month) like below using python

```
Date_Time  A
00:00:00 value

01:00:00 value

..............

23:00:00 value
```

So it is basically the monthly average of each hour. How to do that any suggestion please.

Comment: Is your time column a `datetime` type or `string` type? Is it also the index?

Comment: datetime type @Quang Hoang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
# remove `.dt.floor('H')` if your data is already hourly
hours = df['Date_Time'].dt.floor('H').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df.groupby(hours)['A'].mean()
```